# Magento 2 : problem in the Checkout page : window.checkoutConfig is undefined

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, javascript, payment-methods

I am using Magento 2.0.2 and I have a problem with the Checkout page.

Sometimes there is a JS error appears in the file `/Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote.min.js`:

> TypeError: window.checkoutConfig is undefined

In this case, the Checkout page is not displayed.

[image]

So could anyone please suggest me what are the steps that I follow to find out the solution?

Comment: I am facing same issue have you get the solution of this issue ?

Comment: Try upgrading magento to version 2.1, I'm currently working on 2.1 and I have no issue ( Had the same issue on 2.0.2 )

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced that problem.
When my config file is

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $config = [
        'payment' => [
            'customPayment' => [
                'threed_secure' => $this->get3DSecure(),
            ]
        ]
    ];
    return $config;
}
public function get3DSecure()
{
    //Data from system.xml fields
    return $this->getConfigData('threed_secure');
}
```

Then i have created helper file and define that function here

```
public function get3DSecure(){
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/customPayment/threed_secure');
}
```

Called that function using helper
When i have changed it to following code then it succeds

```
class Payfullapi extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
protected $method;
public function __construct(
    Payfullapi $helper
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
}
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getConfig()
{
     $config = ['payment' => ['customPayment' => [
     'threed_secure' => $this->get3DSecure()
    return $config;
}
/**
* Get config from admin
*/
public function get3DSecure()
{
    //Data from system.xml fields
    return $this->helper->get3DSecure();
} 
}
```

If u want any help just comment here...!
I will help u....!